# Simple way to draw a collection of points

Tags: c#, .net, image, drawimage

Is there any built in way to draw a collection of points? Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
public static Bitmap Draw(this IEnumerable<Point> points)
{
    var horizontallySortedPoints = points.OrderBy(p => p.X).ToArray();
    var verticallySortedPoints = points.OrderBy(p => p.Y).ToArray();

    var leftmost = horizontallySortedPoints.First();
    var rightmost = horizontallySortedPoints.Last();
    var topmost = verticallySortedPoints.First();
    var bottommost = verticallySortedPoints.Last();

    var i = new Bitmap(rightmost.X - leftmost.X + 1, bottommost.Y - topmost.Y + 1);
    foreach (var item in points)
        i.SetPixel(item.X, item.Y, Color.Red);

    return i;
}
```

This seems a lot of work. I have to find myself the leftmost and rightmost point, calculate the width etc. I'm not talking of performance or anything. Just knowing if framework has a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Use Graphics.FromImage + Graphics.DrawLines

Comment: @HansPassant but from which image? I need to pass an `Image` parameter to `Graphics.FromImage`, but how do I get that image? How do I create that image if I have no width and height parameters).

Comment: Your bitmap of course.  Bitmap derives from Image.

Comment: @HansPassant yes I get that. I was trying to avoid all that amount of coding. If I have that bitmap already, then its only a change of two lines. Is there an advantage for `Graphics.DrawLines` over `SetPixel` which I'm using now?

Comment: @HansPassant Graphics.DrawLines doesnt work as expected as well, it connects all the points in the array. I will go ahead with `SetPixel`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way. I ended up doing the same (with some fixes):

```
public static Bitmap Draw(this IEnumerable<Point> points, 
                          Color paintColor = default(Color))
{
    return points.Draw(paintColor, Color.White);
}

public static Bitmap Draw(this IEnumerable<Point> points, Color paintColor, 
                          Color backColor)
{
    return points.Draw(paintColor, backColor, (ps, leftmost, topmost) => ps);
}

public static Bitmap DrawRelative(this IEnumerable<Point> points,
                                  Color paintColor = default(Color))
{
    return points.DrawRelative(paintColor, Color.White);
}

public static Bitmap DrawRelative(this IEnumerable<Point> points,
                                  Color paintColor, Color backColor)
{
    return points.Draw(paintColor, backColor, 
                       (ps, leftmost, topmost) => ps.Select(p => new Point(p.X - leftmost.X, p.Y - topmost.Y)));
}

static Bitmap Draw(this IEnumerable<Point> points, 
                   Color paintColor, Color backColor, 
                   Func<IEnumerable<Point>, Point, Point, IEnumerable<Point>> transformer)
{
    points = points.ToArray();

    Func<IEnumerable<Point>, IEnumerable<Point>> horizontallSorter = ps => ps.OrderBy(p => p.X);
    Func<IEnumerable<Point>, IEnumerable<Point>> verticallSorter = ps => ps.OrderBy(p => p.Y);

    var leftmost = horizontallSorter(points).First();
    var topmost = verticallSorter(points).First();

    var relativePoints = transformer(points, leftmost, topmost).ToArray();

    var rightmost = horizontallSorter(relativePoints).Last();
    var bottommost = verticallSorter(relativePoints).Last();

    var img = new Bitmap(rightmost.X + 1, bottommost.Y + 1);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    {
        g.Clear(backColor);
    }

    foreach (var item in relativePoints)
        img.SetPixel(item.X, item.Y, paintColor);

    return img;
}
```

`Draw` methods draw along the *exact* coordinates specified in `points` input. `DrawRelative` draws by starting from the first non-white point along the X and Y axes, ie all the points are *relatively* shifted so that there are no whitespace from left/top edges.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an easier way to do this. The trick is that, there is no method in `Graphics` class for drawing points, but there is one for drawing rectangles. So all you have to do is to define many rectangles for each of your points and then use `FillRectangles(Brush, Rectangle[])` method to draw your points. Take a look at this code snippet:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Rectangle[] myrects = new Rectangle[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
        myrects[i] = new Rectangle(rnd.Next(0, this.Width), rnd.Next(0, this.Height), 1, 1);
    g.FillRectangles(Brushes.Red, myrects);
}
```

Remember that you must use `FillRectangles` method, not `DrawRectangles`. The latter will draw a 2px width rectangle when used with ordinary `Pens.Red`.

Comment: Hey Ehsan, this did not work. I don't remember what had gone wrong, sorry for being late.